# Doxygen for VHDL : how to ignore portion of code in a file

Tags: vhdl, doxygen

I use doxygen for VHDL files using the option "OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = YES".

I intend to filter warnings '... is undocumented' for declaration of signals, variables, types, component and attributes (id est: almost everything between ARCHITECTURE and BEGIN).

The command [@cond](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcond) seems to be the appropriate answer but I didn't manage to make it work in the VHDL context.

```
--! @cond
signal my_signal : std_logic;
--! @endcond
```

With this code, doxygen outputs the following messages

> warning: Found unknown command '\cond' 
>   warning: Found unknow command '\endcond'

What is the best way to achieve warnings filtering in VHDL context?

**EDIT:**
Doxygen version 1.8.11

Answer (score 1):

The root of the issue is that the tag [@cond](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcond) only work when it is strictly at the beginning of the line. On contrary to the other doxygen comments, it does not work when indented.

example that **works**

```
--! @cond
  signal my_signal_filtered : std_logic;
--! @endcond
```

Note: between ARCHITECTURE and BEGIN, declarations use to be indented one time. That's why I get trapped :)

example that **DOES NOT work** because of the 2 spaces indentation:

```
  --! @cond
  signal my_signal : std_logic;
  --! @endcond
```

Answer (score 0):

I put before my constants/after:

```
  --! @cond CONSTANTS
  --! @endcond
```

and

```
  --! @cond SIGNALS
  --! @endcond
```

before/after signals, e.g. give the condition a name. And in my doxygen.conf the enabled sections is empty:

```
ENABLED_SECTIONS       =
```

Works for me in Doxygen 1.8.6

EDIT: wording was confusing

Comment: Thanks for you post, to know that it works sometimes led me to experiment multiple times until I found what finally happened :)